# llvm/ompiler-rt sanitizer not support aarch64 ilp32: asan_interceptors_vfork.S incompatible with aarch64 ilp32

Tags: arm64, sanitizer

I am building libasan.so from compiler-rt(https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project), after patch the sources with https://patches.linaro.org/patch/129368/, all cpps can be built correctly.
But I get blocked with an ASM (asan/asan_interceptors_vfork.S), in aarch64 this refer to https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/compiler-rt/lib/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors_vfork_aarch64.inc.S.

ERROR INFO:

```
aarch64_be-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: alignment 4 of symbol `_ZN14__interception10real_vforkE' in CMakeFiles/asan.dir/asan/asan_interceptors.cpp.o is smaller than 8 in CMakeFiles/asan.dir/asan/asan_interceptors_vfork.S.o
aarch64_be-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../aarch64_be-linux-gnu/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/asan.dir/asan/asan_interceptors_vfork.S.o: relocation R_AARCH64_P32_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against symbol `_ZN14__interception10real_vforkE' which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
CMakeFiles/asan.dir/asan/asan_interceptors_vfork.S.o: in function `__interceptor_vfork':
llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/./sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors_vfork_aarch64.inc.S:19:(.text+0x10): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/./sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors_vfork_aarch64.inc.S:20:(.text+0x14): relocation truncated to fit: R_AARCH64_P32_LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC against symbol `__interception::real_vfork' defined in .bss section in CMakeFiles/asan.dir/asan/asan_interceptors.cpp.o
aarch64_be-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../aarch64_be-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /cdev/ASAN/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/./sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors_vfork_aarch64.inc.S:20: warning: one possible cause of this error is that the symbol is being referenced in the indicated code as if it had a larger alignment than was declared where it was defined
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
lib/CMakeFiles/asan.dir/build.make:1770: recipe for target 'lib/libasan.so' failed
```

I guess the reason behind is asan_interceptors_vfork.S is in default ILP64 format?

ps: I do have -fPIC when build asan_interceptors_vfork.S.o

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify compiler-rt/lib/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors_vfork_aarch64.inc.S:

```
ldr     x0, [x0, :lo12:_ZN14__interception10real_vforkE]
```

should be

```
ldr     w0, [x0, :lo12:_ZN14__interception10real_vforkE]
```

when building ILP32 code.

Comment: Great thanks. I changed x0 to w0 and R_AARCH64_P32_LDST64_ABS_LO12_NC error disappeared. Still `relocation R_AARCH64_P32_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against symbol `_ZN14__interception10real_vforkE' which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`. I am no sure how to recompile an ASM without C/CPP source with fPIC.

Comment: 7 .comm  _ZN14__interception10real_vforkE,4,4
19 adrp  x0, :got:_ZN14__interception10real_vforkE
20 ldr   w0, [x0, :got_lo12:_ZN14__interception10real_vforkE] solved the issue.